# Probability: Unordered, with replacement, question on example

Tags: probability

Can anyone provide a explanation to how the unordered, with replacement probability using bins is calculated below?  I'm a confused how the inside walls of the bins are combine with the markers.

This is from Berger's book.

Thanks

[image: 1]
[image]

UPDATE:
I read the wiki page at:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

The theorems are really wordy and hard to understand, but the proofs were very helpful!  I understand $\tbinom{n + k - 1}{n}$ now, because it is explained that this reflects placement of the stars over all possible positions.  I'm confused by $\tbinom{n + 1}{k - 1}$ and am curious if it differs from the prior because only max one bin wall is placed between star gaps?

Comment: Look at the explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Comment: ok, I'm reviewing the proof of this Feller Classic p37. Thanks

Comment: @saulspatz I have been careful of what I read on Wiki, however found this suggested Wiki page helpful.  Actually, it was more helpful then Feller's proof in his book (perhaps I'm looking at the wrong one) and the explanation in Berger.

Comment: What is the context of $\binom{n+1}{k-1}$ that confuses you?  I don't see that on the wiki page, but maybe I'm overlooking it.

Comment: Did you mean $\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$, which counts the number of ways of selecting $k$ objects from $n$ types of objects, where at least one object of each type is selected?

Comment: It's part of Theorem 2 of the Wikipedia page.